# Why don't instance variables persist between routes in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I know different ways to make data persist between routes in Sinatra. I'm just trying to understand this more in a Ruby/Object-Oriented way.

My guess is: whenever you rackup a Sinatra app, you're instantiating a Sinatra::Application object. Is it that every time you call a get/post route method, you're creating a new Sinatra::Application so the instance variables will be different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct. Every time you open a new route, a new instance of your rack/sinatra app is re-instantiated.

You can check this out in a very simple way:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Application
  get '/' do
    puts self.object_id
    'Hello world!'
  end
end
```

The output i get from this when opening the browser twice at "localhost:9292" is:

```
Thin web server (v1.6.2 codename Doc Brown)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9292, CTRL+C to stop
70308503790680
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2014 16:10:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12 0.0129
70308504166760
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2014 16:10:22] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12 0.0016
```

Focus on the fourth and sixth line: you can see that the instances have different ids.

If you just output `self`, you can see that it's an instance of the MyApp class:

```
#<MyApp:0x007fbfea3a87c8>
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2014 16:19:54] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12 0.0124
#<MyApp:0x007fbfea460198>
```

Comment: This is not correct. Take a look at what `self` is inside the code block . . . a lot more is going on.

Comment: @NeilSlater
with just `puts self`: #<MyApp:0x007fbfea3a87c8>
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2014 16:19:54] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12 0.0124
#<MyApp:0x007fbfea460198>

Comment: Thanks! I should've known to run that test myself.
Neil Slater, do you care to elaborate what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, seems I was getting confused with other `rack` frameworks.

Comment: Here’s the code: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L885-L887. When a Sinatra app receives a request it `dup`s itself and passes the code to the newly created object, so each request is ultimately handled by a fresh instance.

Comment: Will there ever be a memory issue? I mean, how are the old objects from previous requests discarded?

Comment: I maybe incorrect, but to my belief, since you are probably working with synchronous Sinatra applications, the objects lifecycle ends when you receive the HTML template to your browser (or actually when the rendering is over). After that the Garbage Collector should take care of it.